# Xtragrid repositorycombobox

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

1. My repositorycombobox is showing blank option on default. How do I make the option 1 of the combobox to be the default value.
2. I want to make this repositorycombobox to act like dropdown with no edit function. But if I make it non editable the dropdown wont work. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

1. Set the nulltext property to the repositorycombobox[0]
2. Set the TextEditStyle property of repositorycombobox to DisableTextEditor.